# Proper numpy vectorization

Tags: numpy

I am trying to vectorize my code.  Am I converting

```
def acceleration_1(grid):

  nx = grid.shape[0]
  ny = grid.shape[1]
  acc = np.zeros((nx,ny,2))
  for i in range(1,nx-1):
    for j in range(1,ny-1):
      acc[i,j,0] = grid[i+1,j,0] + grid[i-1,j,0] - 2*grid[i,j,0]
      acc[i,j,1] = grid[i,j+1,1] + grid[i,j-1,1] - 2*grid[i,j,1]
```

to this

```
def acceleration_2(grid):

  nx = np.arange(1,grid.shape[0]-1)
  ny = np.arange(1,grid.shape[1]-1)
  acc = np.zeros((grid.shape[0],grid.shape[0],2))

  acc[nx,ny,0] = grid[nx+1,ny,0] + grid[nx-1,ny,0] - 2*grid[nx,ny,0]
  acc[nx,ny,1] = grid[nx,ny+1,1] + grid[nx,ny-1,1] - 2*grid[nx,ny,1]
```

properly?

I know I could represent this as matrix multiplication as well.  But it just seems cumbersome to have to convert it to matrix operations.  Do I get the best speedup by converting the for loops to an implicit iteration over "nx" and "ny"?

Comment: The first example doesn't work. Why not `[i,j,0]` and `[i,j,1]`? Your array shape is only 2D, as well.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `grid[i,j+1,1]` be `grid[i,j+1,2]`?

Comment: whoops, thanks for that. formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to do convolution. You could do this purely with numpy, similar to what you've shown. Alternatively, we can use built-in convolution functionality:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

k_y = np.array([[1, -2, 1]]).T
k_x = np.array([[1, -2, 1]])

acc = np.zeros_like(grid)
acc[:, :, 0] = convolve2d(grid[:, :, 0], k_y, mode='same')
acc[:, :, 1] = convolve2d(grid[:, :, 1], k_x, mode='same')
```

---

To do it purely with numpy:

```
pad_y = np.pad(grid[:, :, 0], ((1, 1), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
pad_x = np.pad(grid[:, :, 1], ((0, 0), (1, 1)), mode='constant')

up    = pad_y[:-2,  1:-1]
down  = pad_y[2:,   1:-1]
left  = pad_x[1:-1, :-2]
right = pad_x[1:-1, 2:]

acc = np.zeros_like(grid)
acc[:, :, 0] = up   + down  - 2 * grid[:, :, 0]
acc[:, :, 1] = left + right - 2 * grid[:, :, 1]
```

Comment: It seems that you cannot iterate over two separate arrays.  So acc_2 would not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `acc_2`?

Comment: Sorry, the function acceleration_2 does not work properly.  You cannot have arrays of different shapes as arguments to iterate over.

Comment: Ah. You can make them the correct shape by padding (adding zeros to the boundaries).

Comment: No, I meant in my function.  Yours is fine.  You just cant make 2 arrays, nx and ny, and assume that numpy will iterate over all pairs of (nx,ny).

Comment: Purely numpy is bit more difficult (and probably runs slower) but I've added an example.

Comment: I checked your function, it works if you swap k_x and k_y since np.array([[1, -2, 1]]) is a column matrix.  Thanks!